# Is it better to return a buffer, or return a properly sized string?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I wrote a little string compression algorithm as part of an exercise (basically takes the string "aaaabbbccc" and return "a4b3c3"). Code is as follows:

```
char *compress(char string[])
{
    char buffer[256];
    char *pBuffer = buffer;

    char* pStr = (string - 1);
    char currentCharacter = 0;
    int length = 0;

    while (*++pStr != 0)
    {
        currentCharacter = *pStr;
        int currentCharacterLength = 1;

        while ((*(pStr + 1) == currentCharacter) && (*pStr != 0))
        {
            currentCharacterLength++;
            ++pStr;
        }

        *pBuffer++ = currentCharacter;
        *pBuffer++ = (char)currentCharacterLength;
    }

    (*pBuffer) = 0;
    return buffer;
}
```

but looking at it, I'm wondering if I shouldn't create another buffer that actually fits the correct size of the returned string. Obviously, doing so would require more processing time, but would result in a tighter solution. So I'm wondering, what is the general practice on something like this. Is it better (in general) to sacrifice speed for memory, or is it better to just leave it as is?

Or even better, is there a better way to write this solution that I'm not even aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's c++, the better approach is actually to use the std::string type.

Of course, if you are trying to understand how pointers/arrays/strings behave or is dealing with C libraries, you will need to use chars at some point.

The biggest problem when returing  a (char *) - and any other kind of pointers - from a function is how to handle the ownership of that pointer. When do you get rid of the content pointed by this pointer? It can be used in multiple scopes of the code and it can give you all kind of memory leaks and unhandled exceptions.

If you are working with c++, the best approach to return pointers from functions is using std::shared_ptr, because you will not need to handle the memory dealocation of that pointer directly.

Oh, and of course, returning a pointer to memory allocated at stack:

```
char buffer[256];
char *pBuffer = buffer;
```

Is the biggest mistake of your code.

The correct approach would be to allocate that on heap:

```
char *pBuffer = new char[256];
```

Comment: Oh I get that, but I wrote it per the requirements of the exercise.

Comment: +1 Use std::string or a properly sized, null-teriminating `char*` on the heap (essnetially you're recreating the string class). Stack behavior (`char[]`) is undefined for return value, and is kind of messy for passing in-- unless it's bleeding-edge high performance = code smell.

Comment: So is it better overall just not to deal with pointers at all? That seems like that's the whole benefit of using c++ no?

Comment: Returning pointers for locally allocated memory is NOT recommended. There are a lot of uses for pointers in c++, and probably it's one of the reasons to use that language (having control over the memory layout of your program), but not like what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ah, ok. So I just need to not suck. C# has ruined me, heh.

Comment: @sircodesalot: C++ has _smart_ pointers in addition to the regular ones. E.g. the suggested `std::shared_ptr`. That's a much closer equivalent of the C# pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Returning `buffer` is undefined behavior: as soon as your function exists, the content of that buffer can be anything. You should allocate memory dynamically - at the very least, return `strdup(buffer)`.

Since this is C++, using `std::string` is preferred: it will properly manage the memory for you, so even when you do not guess the size of your string correctly, there would be no buffer overruns. Your current solution would fail if the compressed string happens to be longer than 256 characters; a `std::string`-based solution would be free of this shortcoming.

Comment: Why is the content undefined? Shouldn't it return a copy of the buffer?

Comment: Yeah you're right, it is undefined. Changed to `char *buffer = new char[256]` and it seems happier. Why is that?

Comment: @sircodesalot C and C++ arrays are never passed by value to/from functions. They silently decay into a pointer to their first element in such cases.

Comment: Ah, so I'm returning a pointer to a location that has been invalidated. Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per your answer, as usual, it depends...

What is your most limited resource? What is hosting your application? If this is an embedded project, is your application memory large enough to hold a char[256] buffer?

If you are running this program on a full computer setup in Xcode or Eclipse, those IDE's will manage pretty much all of your memory issues on this level, but if you have a large file (E.g. attempting to compress a novel using this schema) then speed is the case to optimize for.

I would be careful with your code if that is the case, as you have a nested loop which could slow the whole compression algorithm to O(string.length()^2) which sucks for large strings (again, like compressing a book) .

So in answer to your question, if you want to use THIS particular method as opposed to Huffman encoding or some other more efficient algorithm (in time and space) then I would keep the current setup you have but remove the double while, use recursion instead to find streams of like letter sequences.

Comment: Ah, recursion. Brilliant, didn't even notice I could do that here.

Comment: The loop nest is actually O(N), despite it being two loops. They share the same control variable `pStr` and both loops increment it.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think there would be any time savings to using recursion, but I think it's a good solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use pointer, you can do:

```
 bool compress(char string[], char* encodedOut, int &encodedSize);
```

So that you will know the size of your encoded array and scope problem would be handled.